# objects in NSArray out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

I have a function with populates the array and then returns it. But in the calling function, the array is not out of scope but all the objects inside it are out of scope.

```
(NSMutableArray *)createObjectWith:(NSString *)result 
{
   NSMutableArray *array =[NSMutableArray array];
   for (int i=0 i<20;i++){

   Wp *newWp =[[Wp alloc]init] ;
   newWp.name= @"a";
   [array addObject:newWp];
 }
 return array;
}
```

calling function:

```
data =[self createObjectWith:stringResult];
```

Comment: Hi you need to post some code what is the exact problem you are facing.

Comment: And what do you mean by "out of scope"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally got to know that its a prob with the debugger. Objects inside are not out of scope. But the debugger says so.

Comment: The debugger data display is pretty flaky and quite often can't display values. Try typing "po myObjectName" (in particular, you'd type "po array") in the debugger console while you're at a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSMutableArray array]
```

returns an auto released array.. If you want to use that array better retain it.

```
data =[[self createObjectWith:stringResult] retain];
```

Also you must release your Wp object after adding to array

```
   Wp *newWp =[[Wp alloc]init] ;
   newWp.name= @"a";
   [array addObject:newWp];
   [newWp release];
```

btw what are you doing with variable result?

Comment: did not make any difference. when i add a breakpoint there, it says 100 objects. But all are out of scope.